# Something went wrong error while creating compose extension in Teams Apps

Tags: microsoft-teams

I’m trying to develop a Teams App using NodeJS SDK referring the following documentation links
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs

I downloaded a hello world sample from github repository (https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs). I created a Microsoft app and followed the steps as per the documentation. I’m getting error ‘Something Went Wrong with App’.

It seems like Teams is not posting query to api/messages endpoint. I tried the same with C# SDK and end up with same error.

Am I missing anything?

[image: Something went wrong Error]

Comment: Could you please put debug points in MessageExtension.cs (C# sample) and see if it is being called when you search?

Comment: I already mentioned in the post, Teams is not triggering api/messages endpoint. So control won't come to debug point.

Comment: Is your bot working fine? Could you please share the bot/compose extension id?